# How to Create a Customized DIV and CSS box

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a **customized box**.

I should have a header for the box, where I can include button or text.
The box should have an image box on the left and text box on the right.
Both the boxes should be of the **same height**.

In the text box, I should be able to place `buttons, text, links etc`.
The background of the whole thing should be able to be customized.

How to do it?

Comment: Please read this for a better understanding about questioning in SO.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you provide a sketch or figure of  what do you exactly want..??

Comment: It is html and css that you need to learn, that's what it's called. https://www.google.com.au/search?q=learn+html+and+css&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=9KqEV9u5AciY0gTVzIfYAw

Answer (score -1):

first of all, if you want to ask a question, others must understand what actually the questioner wants. I hope something like this is what you are asking for.

```css
.customizedBox {
 border: 1px solid #111;
 width: 500px;
 height: 400px;
}
.header {
 background-color: gray;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
}
.imageBox {
 background-color: blue;
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
 height: 350px;
}
.textBox {
 background-color: green;
 float: right;
 width: 50%;
 height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="customizedBox">
  <div class="header">Header
  </div>
  <div class="imageBox">Image Box
  </div>
  <div class="textBox">Text Box
    <button style="display: block;">Button</button>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <a href="#">A link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```